# using functions in swift

Tags: swift, function

I'm new to programming. Please tell me what is wrong in this code! Why am I getting the output "(Function)"?

```
//first function
func admit(person: String) -> String {
  return("\(person) can go")
}
//second function
func deny(person: String) -> String {
  return("\(person) can not go")
}
//third function
func screen(onGuestList: String, person: String) -> (String) -> String {
  if onGuestList == "yes"{
    return admit(person:)
  } else {
    return deny(person:)
  }
}

var outcome = screen(onGuestList: "yes", person: "Sapinder")
print(outcome)
```

I expect the output of "(person) can go", but the actual output is "(Function)".

Answer (score 3):

> Why am I getting the output "(Function)"?

because `screen` function is *not* returning a `String`, it returns `(String) -> String` instead.

Simply, the fix for it is to implement `screen` as:

```
func screen(onGuestList: String, person: String) -> String {
    if onGuestList == "yes"{
        return admit(person: person)
    } else {
        return deny(person: person)
    }
}
```

so what is the difference here? Well, first of all now it returns a string instead of a function that takes a string and returns a string. Also, for calling `admit` and `deny` you have to mention the label (`person`) to pass a parameter to them.

---

*Unrelated tip:*

```
func screen(onGuestList: String, person: String) -> String {    
    return onGuestList == "yes" ? admit(person: person) : deny(person: person)
}
```

<sub>preferably, try to name the functions as verbs instead of nouns, we usually do this for properties (fields) but not methods (behaviors). For example: `displayScreen` instead of `screen`.</sub>

---

**So what's the meaning of returning `(String) -> String`?**

Briefly, Swift does allow such a thing. Consider the following example:

```
func sayHello() -> (String) -> String {
    let functionToReturn: (String) -> String = { name in
        return "Hello \(name)"
    }

    return functionToReturn
}

func takeMy(function: (String) -> String, name: String) {
    print("I am about to print the function:")
    print(function(name))
}

takeMy(function: sayHello(), name: "Sappie")
// I am about to print the function:
// Hello Sappie
```

as you can see, `takeMy` function is that takes another function as a parameter of type `(String) -> String`, therefore we passed `sayHello()` for it since it's signature matches the parameter type.

As a real world example, you could find many methods that parameters as functions when working with collections (for instance). As an example, the `filter` method:

```
func returnMoreThanfive(element: Int) -> Bool {
    return element > 5
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

let filteredArray = array.filter(returnMoreThanfive)
// [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

we passed to `filter` a function that takes an element and returns a boolean. Keep in mind It's just an example to make it more clear to you, however we usually do like this:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0 > 5 }
```

Comment: Also tip: `onGuestList` should be `Bool`

Comment: @user28434 I don't think so :)

Comment: `Person` could be on guest list or not be, it's `Bool`. And body of `screen` acts as if only two options allowed, with 2 outcomes: `allow` and `deny`.  Using `String` here only causes confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
func admit(person: String) -> String {
    return("\(person) can go")
}

//second function
func deny(person: String) -> String {
    return("\(person) can not go")
}

//third function
func screen(onGuestList: String, person: String) -> String {
    if onGuestList == "yes"{
        return admit(person: person)
    } else {return deny(person: person)
    }
}

var outcome = screen(onGuestList: "yes", person: "Sapinder")
print(outcome)
```

> What you were doing were returning a `(String) -> String` instead of `String`

In swift you can return a Function as a return type

Comment: And also not passing the person variable to the admit or deny functions within the screen function.

Comment: why is there (person: person) in your code and why does only (person:) give error?

Comment: @Sappie its the param name for your function `admit ` in swift you have to add the param name in the function call

Comment: but if you want to call it like `admit(person) ` you would have to declare the function like `func admit(_ person: String) -> String`